# How can I set the foreground color of the text of the navigation item in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I set the text of the navigation item by doing this:

```
 viewController.navigationItem.title = @"MyTitle"
```

How can I set the color of the text? I look for that in apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html

But i don't see a method which set the color of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `titleView` instead of a `title` string. The `titleView` is a view and now you are in total charge of how it looks. For example you could use a label with a text color.

Comment: How can I set the font and size of the titleView to match the exact same font as if I am using the title string?

Comment: That isn't what you asked, and is unrelated. Please don't piggyback one question on top of another. If you have a new question, _ask_ a new question! They cost nothing. Meanwhile, I believe I have correctly answered the question you _did_ ask.